# Cast to negated unary expression fails in function templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, unary-operator, typecast-operator

I use the following code to compare arithmetic types. The class template `equal` compares the given arguments for equality and stores the result in the member variable `result`. The class template also provides a cast operator to `bool` in order to be evaluated in conditional statements. I also provide a template deduction guide in order to not have to cast the arguments manually when constructing an `equal` object. This works always when `equal` is evaluated from non-templated functions, but fails to compile in function templates when the expression gets negated by `operator!()`, at least on the current clang compiler (11.0.1). However, it compiles with gcc and msvc. In the code example, the compilation fails in the function template `dummy()`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <concepts>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto abs(T value) -> T
{
    if (value < 0)
        return -1 * value;
    return value;
}


template<std::integral T>
inline constexpr auto integersEqual(const T lref, const T rref) noexcept -> bool
{
    return lref == rref;
}

template<std::floating_point T>
inline constexpr auto floatingPointsEqual(const T lref, const T rref) noexcept -> bool
{
    constexpr T epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() * 1000;
    return abs(lref - rref) <=
           (epsilon * std::max<T>(abs(lref), abs(rref)));
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto arithmeticEqual(const T lref, const T rref) noexcept -> bool
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        return integersEqual(lref, rref);
    }
    else
    {
        return floatingPointsEqual(lref, rref);
    }
}

template<typename T>
class equal final
{
public:
    inline constexpr equal(const T lref, const T rref) noexcept : result(arithmeticEqual(lref, rref)) {}
    inline constexpr operator bool() const noexcept
    {
        return result;
    }
    inline constexpr auto operator!() const noexcept -> bool
    {
        return !result;
    }

private:
    const bool result;
};

// deduction guides for equal
template<typename T1, typename T2>
equal(T1, T2) -> equal<std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>>;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto dummy(const T1 t1, const T2 t2) -> bool
{
    return !equal(t1, t2);                                                            // <- This line fails. If not negated, it works
    //return equal(t1, t2) == false;                                                  // this works
    //return !equal<std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>>(t1, t2);  // this works as well
}


auto main() -> int
{
    return dummy(12, 13);
}
```

(Link to compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/PMcMab)

Compilation fails with the following error message:

```
<source>:67:12: error: invalid argument type 'equal' to unary expression
    return !equal(t1, t2);
```

Adding the `operator!()` to the class template `equal` does not solve this issue. My question is: why doesn't clang accept this code? I don't see a problem with this code. Is this a bug in clang? Usually clang follows the standard more strictly than the other compilers, so I was wondering if both gcc and msvc are accepting this code but really shouldn't. I am suspecting the template argument deduction to be the culprit, since providing a concrete template arguments resolves the issue. Does the deduction fail for some reason I am not aware of?

Comment: Not the solution but an observation: using another custom name for your deduction guide compiles fine for clang.

Comment: return !static_cast<bool>(equal(t1, t2));   solves the issue on caller side but it should work without it since your lambda explicitly states the boolean return type. For me it seems, that clang has an issue here.

Comment: @Secundi Could you explain to me what you mean by "custom name"? I didn't know that it was possible to use a different name for a deduction guide than for the template that is being deduced. When I tried to rename the deduction guide, it didn't compile. What is the syntax?

Comment: You can write `template <class T1, class T2, class U1, class U2>
constexpr auto custom_equal(T1, T2) -> equal<std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>>;`

Comment: If I try your example, I get the following error (which makes sense): "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'U1'
constexpr auto custom_equal(T1, T2) -> equal<std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>>;"   When I remove the parameters U1 and U2, I get the warning "warning: inline function 'custom_equal<int, int>' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
constexpr auto custom_equal(T1, T2) -> equal<std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>>;", and can see in the assembly that clang interprets the call in dummy as a function call instead.

Comment: Aren't you defining a forward declaration of a function template here, instead of a template deduction guide?

Comment: No, it's really a deduction guide. You have to pay attention, that you still call `!equal(t1, t2)`, not `!custom_equal(t1, t2)`! Compiles for me for all common compilers.

Comment: Yes, it compiles, but I am pretty sure that this is a forward declaration, not a deduction guide (see clangs warn). I also, of course, called custom_equal() instead of equal() in dummy(). You are preceeding the function name by "constexpr auto", and give it a trailing return type. It should fail as soon as you try it out on our own compiler instead of compiler explorer, since the linker will complain about the unresolved symbol custom_equal. According to the standard, the signature for tdg is "explicit-specifier(optional) template-name ( parameter-declaration-clause ) -> simple-template-id ;".

Comment: This is how you want me to write the deduction guide, correct? And calling equal instead of the new deduction guide? https://godbolt.org/z/n5o6nd   However, I get the same error on clang 11.0.1. Can you give me a compiler explorer link with your working code?

Comment: I used the trunk, doesn't compile with earlier versions.

Comment: I admit, that it looks strange, also see automatic deduction guides: https://omegaup.com/docs/cpp/en/cpp/language/deduction_guide.html

Comment: I cannot get it to compile in the trunk either, however I am interested, @Secundi, can you please send us a working version on godbolt or some other online compiler where it actually compiles? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it compiles and links and runs in the trunk because it also compiles and links and runs in the trunk if you comment out the custom_equal<> "deduction guide" entirely. See  https://godbolt.org/z/WKGYje. I don't think that the custom_equal<>  comes into play whatsoever - how could it without it being named whatsoever.,

Comment: @DavidBien yes you're right. I also did not want to say, that the different naming makes sense at all, solely that it compiles and seemed to have an effect, that was not really different to the full absence of the guide actually. Seems, that clang fails for proper type deduction in the presence of at least that specific unary operator. From the error message itself, it doesn't sound like clang just does not look for implicit conversion, which I first thought it might be the origin of issues here.

Comment: So some behavior has changed between clang 11 and the trunk because now, without the deduction guide at all being present, it compiles in the trunk but doesn't compile in that same configuration in clang 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda think it is a bug in clang. I fiddled around with this for a while.

I tried:

```
return equal( t1, t2 ).operator !();
```

which clang didn't like, but the other compilers did.

Clang said:

```
<source>:69:27: error: member reference base type 'equal' is not a structure or union
    return equal( t1, t2 ).operator !();
```

an interesting error.

Also if you just do this:

```
bool dummy2( int t1, unsigned t2)
{
    return !equal(t1, t2);
}
```

it compiles fine. So it has something to do with the deduction guide in combination with the invocation of the deduction guide inside of a template method.

Finally, this compiles:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto dummy(const T1 t1, const T2 t2) -> bool
{
    typedef decltype( equal(t1, t2) ) _TyEqual;
    static_assert( std::is_same_v< _TyEqual, equal< std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>>> );
    return !_TyEqual(t1, t2);
}
```

which coupled with the other errors makes me think that the error is that clang uses some intermediate type of some sort when applying the deduction guide. Once you spell out the type to clang, it likes it...

Anyway, interesting problem and I gained a bit of knowledge about deduction guides in the process.

Comment: The error message is indeed very interesting. I added the following method to the class equal:' inline constexpr auto b() -> bool {return result;}'    When I try to invoke this method in the dummy template as 'return equal(t1, t2).b();', I get the same error message about equal not being a structure or union. If I store the result in a temporary variable, and invoke the method b(), it works. Really seems like a clang bug to me now.

Comment: I agree. Will you give them a bug?

Comment: Yes, I am going to do so soon. Since self-registration on the llvm bug-tracker is disabled, I had to wait for them to approve my registration. I just received a mail from them, so I will search the bug tracker first for this error, and if I think this issue hasn't been reported yet, shrink this example down to the bare minimum and submit it. After I have submitted it, I will post the link to the bug ticket here, and if they recognize it as a bug, accept your answer as "the solution". Thank you again for your valuable hints.

Comment: While I was coming up with a shrinked down example for the bug tracker, I also tried to compile the code with the current trunk of clang, which works. Guess I should have tried that out beforehand. It seems to me that this issue has been adressed already, so I will not create a new bug ticket for this issue and instead hope that the next release (probably 11.0.2) will fix this issue.